# How set background Image in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to add a drawable in my recyclerview to cover whole the card view but it is set to each card separately I want one single background 
PS: See image for further clarification

I have add background in cardview and recyclerview but nothing changed

here is my recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/harampak"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="Suplications/Dua"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

card item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="After Rainfall"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

shown on androidstudio
[image]

on device
[image]

Comment: you can not set background in recyclerview.

Comment: can i change color?

Comment: where you can change color?

Comment: Give background on recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set different background images in each RecyclerView item. Then you need to two thing in RecyclerVeiw Adapter.

1. Images array And
2. set these Images as background of CardView
   in onBindViewHolder method.

like this :

```
      public int[] images = { R.drawable.image, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4 };

        @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(images[position % 4]);
    }

    public class LectureViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           public CardView cardView;
           cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }
```

and they will  be repeate after complete Images Array.